# Is it normal for WmiPrvSE.exe to consume 10% CPU non-stop?

Tags: windows-vista, wmi, cpu-usage

Resource Monitor shows Average CPU for WmiPrvSE.exe is 10%. Is that normal? This is just a 64-bit Vista laptop with an Intel P7550 (Core 2 Duo @ 2.26GHz) and 4G RAM. It's not running anything special *that i know of* (e.g., firefox, photoshop, etc). But the WmiPrvSE.exe runs at this rate even immediately after booting up.

Comment: Is it connected to a domain?

Comment: No. I did replace AVG with MS Security Essentials and now WmiPrvSE.exe averages 5% ... correlation == causation? Is there any way to see what processes are using WMI?

Comment: @Ben, what laptop brand is it? ... If it is HP, it could be the wireless monitor... http://blog.superuser.com/2011/02/28/the-hp-cpu-assassin/...

Comment: @William It is an HP. But suspending those processes (and everything else from HP) doesn't seem to help. That link does provide some leads though. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10 Enterprise 1607, Lenovo X1, Domain connected --> `!RtlUserThreadStart` 10-25% nonstop. Total CPU Time and cycles is second only to System Idle Process